# How to have a reference of the Promise in the results using Promise.AllSettled

Tags: javascript, promise

I've a stupid question about JS and Promise AllSettled.

```
const ids = [1,10,33,40];

const promises = ids.map(id => getObjectById(id))

const result = await Promise.allSettled(promises)

result.map(item => {
  if (item.status === 'fullfiled') {
    console.log(value)
    // {
    //   key: value
    //   key1: value2
    //   key3: [
    //     ...
    //   ]
    // }

    // how can I have a referecen of the ids array here for each promise
  }
})
```

I have an array of functions that make api call using an id to fetch its correspondent object. But, in the results, there is reference of the ID. So I was wondering if is there a JS way to handle this and what would be the most perfomance way to handle it. I want to have the a reference of the promise that generated that result.

Comment: What do you mean by "a reference of the promise that generated that result" ?

Comment: In the console.log(value) I don't have the id.

Comment: @gmilleo you should edit that into the question itself, that you want to retain those integer values in the awaited output.

Comment: Ive updated my question. Is it more clear?

Comment: @gmilleo yes much better, I've added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preserve those values in the final Promise:

```
const result = await Promise.allSettled([
  Promise.all([1, getObjectById(1)]),
  //...
])
```

and then in the results:

```
results.map(([id, item]) => {...});
```

**NOTE** since you're using `Promise.allSettled`, your `item` could be an error!